# Need to understand in Netezza, how to see all view references

Tags: netezza

I come from SQL Server and Oracle of 15 years, and am having some conundrums in getting some fundamentals out of Netezza :). I have a database with 500 views, that I need to understand all of what they are referencing.

I imagine, there must be a better way to do this than looking through all the DDL. Unfortunately I do not know the internals of Netezza well, and am attempting to look through the system tables, but not finding what I am looking for.

I tried doing some google searches and searches through here and wasn't finding what I was looking for, so I am hoping someone here has a magic query to help with this, otherwise this will be a very daunting task :).

Answer (score 1):

You need to Go to the unix prompt and run a script called nz_view_references. I started reproducing it once as a piece of SQL and it IS possible to do so - at least with the regular expression toolkit installed. But never quite finished it :)

The script contains sql against catalog tables and the help section specifies these tables to be relevant for a grant select... _T_OBJECT, _T_OBJECT_CLASSES, _T_DATABASE

Hope it helps...